# Catching enter on KeyUp event in winforms application

Tags: winforms, events

I'm working on a winforms application. I have a simple `login screen` and when i press `enter key` i catch it in `KeyUp(...) event` and if credentials are not valid i show a `MessageBox`.
After that when i press Enter again it's caught by the MessageBox and the LoginForm both and there is a infinite loop that firstly message box disappears and then LoginForm is entered with invalid credentials and MessageBox is shown again.
The `key event` should be active for only the MessageBox than i should need to press Enter again for submitting the form again.

How can i handle this situation?

Comment: Please do not highlight random words as "code".

Comment: @SLaks: Should have said "please `do not` highlight `random` words `as` code". :)

Comment: Some words are so meaningful to me (: Ok i'll pay attention to this.

Comment: @gesus: That doesn't mean they're `code`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you create a Login button to handle the credential verification, and then set the button as the [Accept Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) of your form. It's built for handling this sort of issues. i.e. Once enter is pressed, it would appear as if the button was clicked.

See [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the `KeyDown` event.

While the message box is open, KeyDown will be swallowed by it.
(As opposed to KeyUp, which will fire after it is closed)